# Eclipse doesn't show the right error line

Tags: java, html, eclipse, spring, thymeleaf

I'm doing a project using spring mvc with the spring tools suite ide and using thymeleaf with html5. When i have a unclosed tag eclipse gives me this error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="index", line 727 - column 35

a div tag must end with </div>
```

but when i go to that line and column there are no unclosed tags or div tags. This happened to me with other tags like `input` or `img` but they always tell me a wrong line and column i have to search the entire file to find the right unclosed tag. Is there a way to fix this??

Comment: i don't know if you have webtools, maybe it can help you validate your html. The link is [link]http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/ also post all the code from the page, maybe there was something you missed.

Comment: I have used thymeleaf. It normally points to the correct line. You may want to validate your html as xhtml

Comment: are you using a layout to build the html file? The line number refers to the fully built html page to be viewed.

Comment: i am using the spring tools suites ide, i dont know what is a layout?